# url rewrite - redirect to HTTP except one page

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to have one single page `mysubdir/checkout.php` to be secured using SSL.
e.g. `https://www.mywebsite.com/fr/checkout`, where `fr` is the language code.

All other pages should be redirected back to http.

This is what I have in .htaccess but it does not work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/checkout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/fr/checkout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

##### Checkout #####
RewriteRule ^/(fr|en)/checkout/?$ mysubdir/checkout.php?lang=$1 [QSA]
```

However when I entered: `https://www.mywebsite.com/fr/checkout` it redirects to `https://www.mywebsite.com/mysubdir/checkout.php?lang=fr`. Why?

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
#redirect checkout.php from http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule checkout\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect all requests except "checkout.php" from https to http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule !checkout\.php$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect only **/checkout.php** to https.

Comment: But in my case checkout.php is also rewritten to /fr/checkout.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? are there any other rules or htaccess ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `THE_REQUEST` variable instead of `REQUEST_URI` since your last is changing `REQUEST_URI` to something else.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/fr/checkout
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /fr/checkout
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

##### Checkout #####
RewriteRule ^/?(fr|en)/checkout/?$ mysubdir/checkout.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache when you test this.